# Using the Count function with both "equals" and "not equals" at the same time on a 2d list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In a 2 dimensional list like the one below, is there any way, using the Count function to count all rows where first column equals 1, second equals 2 and third does not equal 3?

I tried Count[Data,{1,2,_?(#!=3&)}] - but it doesn't work :(. Am I doing something wrong using patterns?

1 2 3

2 2 3

1 1 1

1 2 1

1 3 2

3 3 3

3 2 1

1 2 2

Many thanks,
m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think your pattern is awry. Try

`Count[data, {1, 2, x_ /; x != 3}]`

Comment: Perfect! it worked. Thank you very much Mark, now I understand much better how to use patterns in kind of situations.

Answer (score 1):

The original version works fine!  (Although it's better form to use lower case variable names, i.e. 'data'.)

```
Data = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 5}};

Count[Data, {1, 2, _?(# != 3 &)}]
```

> 2

You could also use `Except`:

```
Count[Data, {1, 2, Except[3]}]
```

> 2